# Can we create the outgoing webhook programmatically in Microsoft teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Can we create the outgoing webhook programmatically in Microsoft teams?I dont want to use BOT or do we have any mechanism where i will get the notification when user send message to the channel or create channel in the account?

Comment: As of now there are no APIs to automate Connector configuration flow. Please have a look at [Outgoing Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook) documentation. Please let us know your scenario with more details.

Comment: Hi Wajeed thanks for quick reply! I want to integrate Microsoft teams in our application and our application should get notified as and when some message posted in channel or new channel is created.Yes I have seen the way to create webhook but user needs to configure  it on their account then only we can get this notification I don't want this I want to do it on behalf of user I don't want to let the user to do this task.Thats why i was asking whether their any way where can set this webhook programmatically on behalf of user?Or do we have any plan in the future?

Comment: Or do we have any methods for polling this details where I will get delta?

Comment: As of now there are no API's to programmatically generate webhook. we can not assure any timeline for it. About notification - notification and activity API's are currently being worked on. probably this can help you but there is no timeline that we can assure you.